# Is it possible to call doInBackground from onPostExecute?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    asyntask.execute();   
 }
```

I'm reading data from some API. Is it possible to call `doInBackground()`  from `onPostExecute`?

I want do it recursively like (network task and update in UI ) for 5 times. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: doInBackground is executed to perform the network task, and onPostExecute is executed after doInBackground to make the UI changes after the doInBackground is complete

Comment: i want do it recursively like (network task and update in UI ) for 5 times so is it right to call doInbackground from onPostexecute.  @ArjunIssar ,@masked man

Comment: You cannot make recursive calls. Create different asynctasks. You have to let the asynctask complete, then fire another one,

Comment: Mark the question answered if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting the `AsyncTask` again from inside `onPostExecute` is a horrible idea. As you want to do it recursively like 5 times for network calls along with UI update, I would like to suggest you to keep an interface to keep track of the `AsyncTask` call.

So here's an example about how you can achieve the behaviour. You may create an `interface` like this.

```
public interface MyResponseListener {
    void myResponseReceiver(String result);
}
```

Now you declare the interface in your `AsyncTask` class too. So your `AsyncTask` may look like this.

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    // Declare an interface 
    public MyResponseListener myResponse;

    // Now in your onPostExecute
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        // Send something back to the calling Activity like this to let it know the AsyncTask has finished. 
        myResponse.myResponseReceiver(result);
    }
}
```

Now you need to implement the `interface` you've created already in your `Activity` like this. You need to pass the reference of the interface to the `AsyncTask` you're starting from your `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyResponseListener {
    // Your onCreate and other function goes here 

    // Declare an AsyncTask variable first
    private YourAsyncTask mYourAsyncTask;

    // Here's a function to start the AsyncTask
    private startAsyncTask(){
        mYourAsyncTask.myResponse = this;
        // Now start the AsyncTask 
        mYourAsyncTask.execute();
    }

    // You need to implement the function of your interface 
    @Override
    public void myResponseReceiver(String result) {
        if(!result.equals("5")) {
            // You need to keep track here how many times the AsyncTask has been executed. 
            startAsyncTask();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation Thank you @Reaz Murshed

Answer (score 1):

doInBackground() is called before calling onPostExecute.

Since you cannot perform network tasks on the UI thread, an AsyncTask is created.
The AsyncTask executes in the background, performing the network task on the worker thread. Then after the background task is completed, onPostExecute() is called that makes the UI changes on the UI thread.

This should help : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The `AsyncTask` class is used to do some work in background and publish the results to the `MainThread` so it's **generally** not possible because the work that's being done in the worker thread may not be doable in `MainThread`, (like the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when you do networking in `MainThread`).
I suggest you to make an array of your jobs and call the `execute()` method of your subclass of `AsyncTask` and it will serialize the jobs to be done in a worker thread.